# Deleting customized workflows from 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow

I created a document library in sp 2010 enterprise.
I customized the 'Global' Approval workflow, calling it "My Workflow"
When I choose the Workflows ribbon tab for the library, I see "My WorkFlow"
But it is not visible in Sharepoint Designer, not under Workflows, all files
or the list workflows assigned to this library.

So how do I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!
It is under the workflows section for the local Content Type 'Document' in the library.

Comment: To me, this is a user funding the answer to his own question, and sharing the solution :)